# rqt_plot has a Qt4 and Qt5 conflict

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest update seems to have a problem with qt4 vs qt5 but it could be something else that updated along with all the kinetc updates.

When I try to launch rqt_plot I get the following, the RuntimeError at the end shows up for other projects as well:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rqt_plot", line 6, in <module>
    from rqt_plot.plot import Plot
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .data_plot import DataPlot
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .pyqtgraph_data_plot import PyQtGraphDataPlot
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/pyqtgraph_data_plot.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pyqtgraph import __version__ as pyqtgraph_version
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .Qt import QtGui
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/Qt.py", line 104, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore and PyQt5.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255551/rqt_plot-has-a-qt4-and-qt5-conflict/) by [Curt](https://answers.ros.org/users/12666/curt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a problem with *pyqtgraph*. You can use rqt_plot without *pyqtgraph*. It will use *MatPlot* then. Uninstall *pyqtgraph* with:

```
sudo apt remove python-pyqtgraph
```

If you want to use *pyqtgraph* anyways, consider to install the newest version from github as mentioned in this post: https://answers.ros.org/question/236924/pyqtgraph-not-working-in-ros-kinetic/

---

Originally posted by [neumann-d](https://answers.ros.org/users/34256/neumann-d/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0